# Windows - How to redirect all console output to text file? The console program is called by another software that I can't control

Tags: windows, console

It's a pretty complicated issue (at least for me).

GUI software at a given moment, calls console software, which outputs something to console and quits. I'd like to save those results to a text file, but I can't call the console software myself.

Is there anyway to globally record all console outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html). Its [settings](http://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html) has:

- [Default terminal](http://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html) feature; You need to enable it and add you GUI software to the hooked executables list.
- [Console output automatic logging](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html#id2679); Just enable the ‘Log console output’ and specify the folder where logs will be stored. Don't forget to enable (it's enabled by default) ‘Inject ConEmuHk’.